# Why can't I connect remotely with SQL Server Report Server from SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So I have SQL Server Report Server installed on a Windows Server 2016 Standard.  It appears to be configured correctly in Report Server Configuration Manager and I can connect to it on the local machine using SQL Server Management Studio.  However, when I try to connect to it from my windows 10 workstation, living in the same domain, I get "The reporting services instance could not be found".  I've opened ports 80 and 443 via Windows Firewall to all traffic.  Any help with trouble shooting this issue?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using SSMS? Why not use the web interface?

Comment: Not for me, for my co-worker.  She wants to be able to use Object Explorer in SSMS.  She's the developer, I'm just an admin trying to help her out.  I haven't worked with Reporting Services since it lived in IIS (circa 2012), lol.  This is a strange new world...

Comment: She says that there are a whole lot of settings you can't set with the portal, such as allowing the users to have their own folder.

Comment: I can't think of any settings you can't access via the portal, if I am honest. Folders, and their permissions, and certainly something you can do in the web portal.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not just going to put her off...

Comment: I sounds like a made up excuse if I am honest. User settings isn't even something you can manage in that connection according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/connect-to-a-report-server-in-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: They claim it's as easy as 1, 2, 3, but not getting the 1, 2, 3 results.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/connect-to-a-report-server-in-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15